# Remove slash after redirect

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm trying to do a redirect from http to https with the following code and when accessing a context it gives me a "/" at the end.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTPS}! On
RewriteRule (. *) Https: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI}
```

This is the problem when I put the url with the context appers the slashs at the end:

http://mydomain/ip -> https://mydomain/ip***/***

What's exactly the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:
[Credits](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash)

```
## Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

## Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: but in the second RewriteRule not appears https. In the first i see that redirect from http to https but in the second apply from the first condition?

Comment: @GuifIfyes it is